# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. While calling put api?

Tags: api, flutter, rest

I have one issue while working on flutter, whenever i tried to calling the http.put request strange issue occurred.

Here is my main code.

```
saveBookMarksLogin(id) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var bookmarkData = {
      "userId": userId,
      "newsFeedId": id,
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.put(
        Uri(
          scheme: 'http',
          host: host,
          port: 3000,
          path: '/v1/saveBookmark',
        ),
        body: bookmarkData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      );

      if (response.body != null) {
        prefs.setStringList("bookmarkIds", [id]);
        return json.decode(response.body);
      }
    } on SocketException {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "No internet connection",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIos: 1,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      );
    }
  }
```

Stack trace of issue while debugging..

```
I/flutter (23979): error NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (23979): Receiver: null
I/flutter (23979): Tried calling: length
I/flutter (23979): stacktrace #0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter (23979): #1      _Uri._uriEncode  (dart:core-patch/uri_patch.dart:44:23)
I/flutter (23979): #2      Uri.encodeQueryComponent  (dart:core/uri.dart:1103:17)
I/flutter (23979): #3      mapToQuery.<anonymous closure> 
package:http/src/utils.dart:19
I/flutter (23979): #4      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure>  (dart:_internal/cast.dart:286:8)
I/flutter (23979): #5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach  (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
I/flutter (23979): #6      CastMap.forEach  (dart:_internal/cast.dart:285:13)
I/flutter (23979): #7      mapToQuery 
package:http/src/utils.dart:17
I/flutter (23979): #8      Request.bodyFields= 
package:http/src/request.dart:128
I/flutter (23979): #9      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed 
package:http/src/base_client.dart:163
I/flutter (23979): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (23979): #10     BaseClient.put 
package:http/src/base_client.dart:76
I/flutter (23979): #11     put.<anonymous closure> 
package:http/http.dart:94
I/flutter (23979): #12     _withClient 
package:http/http.dart:166
I/flutter (23979): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (23979): #13     put 
package:http/http.dart:93
I/flutter (23979): #14     _NewsPageState.saveBookMarksLogin (package:i
```

Flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.21359.1], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 2.0.6 at C:\Program Files\flutter
• Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (2 weeks ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
• Engine revision 05e680e202
• Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\lkrja\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.3)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.31129.286
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\lkrja\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
• Windows (desktop)                  • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.21359.1]
• Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
• Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.56

• No issues found!

Comment: This might be coming from the Json part of the code. What are you doing with the JSON object after you return it?

Comment: it can not give me any responce json.decode(response.body) here